# MAUI iOS does not fit the screen

Tags: ios, maui

When deploying my MAUI iOS application in debug mode, it is displaying the application as a smaller window inside of the iPhone screen.

Almost like a smaller window inside of a window.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this by adding a MAUI splash screen, which I had accidentally removed previously.

```
<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />
```

You can track this issue at https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11951

Comment: Don't forget to Clean the project before Deploy it again